# In which file (or path) are the Docker images and containers stored?

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, boot2docker

I installed Docker Toolbox on Windows 10.

I use the VM where my storage is:

C:\Users\ ***username*** \.docker\machine\machines\default\disk.vmdk

However, as I add and remove 100mb worth of images, the size of this file on my hard-drive is barely changing. boot2docker.iso is also same space.

So I was wondering, where are the Images and Containers really stored?

Answer (score 0):

Containers only work on "Linux". So, `Docker Toolbox` actually creates a VM to run your containers.

So these images/containers/volumes are inside your VM or rather in that disk file.

I believe the disk created is of fixed size and hence you don't actually see any difference in size.

Also, for Windows 10, you should use [`Docker for Windows / Docker Desktop`](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I cannot get Docker for Windows since I have Windows 10 Home. I've been reading around and there is not fix for it today, which is pretty silly for an open source project...

Comment: Nonetheless, you should be able to find containers/images/volumes inside the VM that `Docker Toolbox` creates.